# How do I add data into a new row of a database table

Tags: java, database, derby

I am using netbeans version 7.3.1 and I simply would like to take data that the user enters into multiple text fields, in the Netbeans GUI and then to take that data and use it to create a new row in a table, in the database, I am using it to create new users. I am using derby embedded.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) and [JDBC(TM) Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Comment: Also, which GUI framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Java Database Connectivity](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/overview-141217.html) (JDBC) in order to connect Java code to your database.

The SQL command is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Using Java and the JDBC library, this becomes:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table_name " + "VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...");
```

As MadProgrammer suggested, you could also use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "value1");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "value2");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: A `PreparedStatement` would be preferred as it removes the risk of potential SQL injection attacks